# How to open multiple R scripts at once?

Tags: rstudio

I am trying to a shortcut such that I can open all the r scripts in a file at once without clicking multiple times of open files.

[image]

I have already tried `find in files` but it cannot read all the files at once...
Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4306

Comment: Really hope that they can consider to add this function, it is so inconvenient to ctrl+o multiple times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over a vector of file names calling `rstudioapi::documentOpen()`.  For example, to open all files with a `.R` extension in the working directory:

```
lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.R$"), rstudioapi::documentOpen)
```